# Delphi 2010 for loop count

Tags: delphi, for-loop, delphi-2010

I have a problem with a For Loop. I need it to count a random amount of shopping sprees and amounts but display them in order like below. It also needs to take the amount of sprees and display it before.

Currently it displays total sprees as 0 and only displays 20 sprees which is not random.

You have won a total of 3 shopping sprees

On spree #1 you may spend R100

On spree #2 you may spend R341

On spree #3 you may spend R451

TotalCost := 0;

Sum := 0;

```
ListHead := 'Max per spree is R500.00 Max number of sprees 20';
lstNumber.Items.Add(ListHead);

  SpreeWon := 'You have won  ' + inttostr(Sum) + ' shopping sprees';
  lstNumber.Items.Add(SpreeWon);

for Count := 0 to 20 do
begin
    Sum := Random(Count);
    Prize := Random(500) + 1;
    ListItems := 'On spree # ' + inttostr(Sum) + ' you may spend R' + inttostr(Prize);
    lstNumber.Items.Add(ListItems);
    TotalCost := TotalCost + Prize;
end;
begin
    Cost := 'Total prize value : R' + inttostr(TotalCost);
    lstNumber.Items.Add(Cost);
end;
```

Comment: @Ken that's why I posted the link: it tells you to mark your question not with the tag, but mention in the question how much you want the answers to reveal. Maybe I should have made that more clear (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not doing what your requirement asks for.  You are displaying 20 sprees because you hard-coded it to generate 20 sprees, not a random number of sprees.

Try something more like this instead:

```
ListHead := 'Max per spree is R500.00 Max number of sprees 20';
lstNumber.Items.Add(ListHead);

Count := Random(20) + 1;
TotalCost := 0;

SpreeWon := 'You have won  ' + IntToStr(Count) + ' shopping sprees';
lstNumber.Items.Add(SpreeWon);

for I := 1 to Count do
begin
  Prize := Random(500) + 1;
  TotalCost := TotalCost + Prize;
  ListItems := 'On spree # ' + IntToStr(I) + ' you may spend R' + IntToStr(Prize);
  lstNumber.Items.Add(ListItems);
end;

Cost := 'Total prize value : R' + IntToStr(TotalCost);
lstNumber.Items.Add(Cost);
```

Comment: Thank you Remy. Your changes fixed the problem.