# Delphi 2010 while loop

Tags: delphi, while-loop, delphi-2010

I have a problem with a While Loop.

I need the TotalCost to be displayed in SpreeWin and the Shopping sprees to be shown as below

Your spending limit that you have won is R 890

On spree #1 you may spend R100

On spree #2 you may spend R340

On spree #3 you may spend R450

```
  ListHead := 'Max per spree is R500.00 Max limit is R10000.00';
  lstLimit.Items.Add(ListHead);

  Count := random(20) + 1;
  MaxCost := random(10000) + 1;
  TotalCost := 0;


  SpreeWon := 'Your spending limit that you have won is  R' + IntToStr(TotalCost);
  lstLimit.Items.Add(SpreeWon);


  while TotalCost <= MaxCost do
    begin
         Prize := Random(500) + 1;
         TotalCost := TotalCost + Prize;
         ListItems := 'On spree # ' + IntToStr(Count) + ' you may spend R' + IntToStr(Prize);
         lstLimit.Items.Add(ListItems);
    end;

 Cost := 'Total prize value : R' + IntToStr(TotalCost);
 lstLimit.Items.Add(Cost);
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? please note the `homework` tag is deprecated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100

Comment: I need the TotalCost displayed (SpreeWon := 'Your spending limit that you have won is  R' + IntToStr(TotalCost)) as it displays 0 now and I need the On spree #1 you may spend R100 to show each spree in numerical order

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi 2010 for loop count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485256/delphi-2010-for-loop-count). There's even an accepted answer with a comment thanking the person answering for the working solution.

Comment: @Ken - As far as I understand, the poster figured a definite number of iterations won't work for the assignment and switched to using a while loop instead of a for loop. And he asked this question when he got stuck. But that's only my guess of course. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding the item for total cost while TotalCost is 0, insert it when you've got it. For the spree count, well you should count it:

```
  var
    SpreeCount: Integer;
    ..


  ..
  TotalCost := 0;

  // comment the below
  // SpreeWon := 'Your spending limit that you have won is  R' + IntToStr(TotalCost);
  // lstLimit.Items.Add(SpreeWon);

  SpreeCount := 0; // <--

  while TotalCost <= MaxCost do
    begin
         Prize := Random(500) + 1;
         TotalCost := TotalCost + Prize;

         Inc(SpreeCount); // <--
         // substitute SpreeCount for Count in the below
         ListItems := 'On spree # ' + IntToStr(SpreeCount) + ' you may spend R' + IntToStr(Prize);
         lstLimit.Items.Add(ListItems);
    end;

 Cost := 'Total prize value : R' + IntToStr(TotalCost);
 lstLimit.Items.Add(Cost); 

  // insert SpreeWon
  SpreeWon := 'Your spending limit that you have won is  R' + IntToStr(TotalCost); // <--
  lstLimit.Items.Insert(0, SpreeWon); // <--
```

Comment: Thanks alot Sertac. This has helped alot